# Do ACL permissions differentiate between UNIX file types?

Tags: linux, acl

When setting ACL permissions such as

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:shared_group:rwx  /mnt/shared_resource
```

do the permissions of `shared_group` extent to every type of file (directory, symlink, regular file, fifo, socket, etc) without  file type differentiation ? Is there a way to set ACL for `shared_group` such that directories inherit one set of permissions, but regular files (or at least everything non-directory) - different set of permissions ?

Comment: @Christopher So in other words, depending on the mask, directories and files do in fact get different permissions, right ? That's essentially the answer I was seeking, but could you maybe post an answer instead of a comment to go into details  ? Like, why exactly files will get `rw-`  instead of `rwx` ?